# ExtJS - vertical align of textfield and their labels separately

Tags: extjs, alignment, vertical-alignment

So I have HBox with 5 textfields. All of them have labels

```
xtype: 'container',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'top',
        pack: 'center'
    },

items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'few words label'
        flex: 10,
        bind: '{boundObject}'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'label'
        flex: 12,
        bind: '{boundObject}'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'label'
        flex: 5,
        bind: '{boundObject}'
        },
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'few words label'
        flex: 7,
        bind: '{boundObject}'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'label'
        flex: 12,
        bind: '{boundObject}'
    }]
```

When the screen is full-width there is no problems with this layout. But when I make screen smaller and labels become to have more than 1 line (those with text 'few words label', textfields are no more aligned vertically to each other as labels are higher and push some textfields futher to the bottom. Is there a way to deal with this problem with the same layout or I must to separate labels from textfields?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the issue or atleast a image or something showing your issue?

Comment: You mean smaller screen by using resize ? If yes then you adjust your container items by using onResize

Comment: create some fiddle I will solve it there itself

Comment: @UDID . That was that problem. In fact it was resizing good way but not every time. I realized that because every time I was opening Chrome Dev Tools, textfields were moved to their proper positions and were aligned properly. Adding resize listener and updateLayout method solved a problem